# Selecting rows which have different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows which have 10 different soru_id from end of the table.  It has to return only red marked rows. Table structure and red marked rows are in picture below. How can i do it?
http://i47.tinypic.com/2132iir.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "end of the table"? Are the order of rows based on a timestamp column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the soru_id decides the beginning/end of the table

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT soru_id
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
 ORDER BY date_created DESC 
 LIMIT 10;
```

In case you need the full row instead of soru_id alone. then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <YOUR_TABLE> a
JOIN
  ( SELECT soru_id,
           MAX(date_created) date_created
   FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
   GROUP BY soru_id LIMIT 10) b ON a.soru_id = b.soru_id
AND a.creation_date = b.creation_date
```

Comment: Clearly `soru_id` does not determine the order as can be seen from the example, otherwise the first row would be included in the results. I'd guess that it's column called `crea...` that decides the order... `creation_date` perhaps?

Comment: @MarkByers Looks like that. Also jus realized that OP is looking for the full row... Will update the answer